# Canvas.drawTextOnPath doesn't scales text along with canvas scale

Tags: android, canvas, custom-view, drawtext

I am trying to draw a text on curved path. But when I scale up the canvas, text gets blurred.
Here's the code I've tried

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    float midX = (maxX + minX) / 2;
    float midY = (maxY + minY) / 2;
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(minX, minY);
    canvas.scale(this.scaleX, this.scaleY);
    if (curvingAngle != 0) {
        drawCurveText(canvas, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    } else
        canvas.drawText(text, mOrigin[0], mOrigin[1], textPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}

private void drawCurveText(Canvas canvas,float offsetX, float offsetY, float scale) {
    // Path Calculation
    Path textPath;
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, this.textPath, hOffset, 0.0f, this.getPaint());
}
```

It gives following results

Before Scale[image]
After Scale[image]

The same code without curvingAngle (canvas.drawText) works perfectly with scaling.
Any help would be appreciated...